# I read nifti image (.nii) using simpleITK. Image is in Image<float,3> format. How to convert this image into C# array and display it on unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-processing, itk

```
    void ReadImage(string path)
    {
        eText.text = path;   
        itk.simple.Image input = SimpleITK.ReadImage(path);
        Debug.Log(input);
    }
```

**Debug.Log gives Image<float,3>**
I need to convert this image into C# array similar to sitk.GetArrayFromImage() method available in python.

Answer (score 0):

In CSharp (and the other wrapped languages), you can get copy of an Image's with the GetBufferAsFloat method.

You can see it in use in the SimpleITK CSharp Integration example:

https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_CSharp_docs.html